# python - setting instance variable within the instance

Tags: python, class, oop, set, instance

I have the following tile class which got some instance variables such as UNMAPPED,FREE etc. 
Those instance variables get a default value once new instance is created, but i want to set some of this variables from a method within the instance itself.
when im trying to do so, it seems the the new value is not saved but when im doing it without any method it seems to work.
How can it be?

```
class tile():
    def __init__(self):
       self.FREE        =  0
       self.UNMAPPED    =  1
    def set_tile(self,newVal):
       self.FREE = newVal
```

so that :
    tile1 = tile()
    tile1.set_tile(20)  -> tile1.FREE = 0
but, 
    tile1.FREE = 20 -> tile1.FREE = 20

thanks for your help

Comment: The method works wonderfully. I imagine your real example is a lot more complex and you have simplified it

Comment: Post how did you check `tile1.FREE` after you did `tile1.set_tile(20)`, because it seems to me you reassign to `tile1.FREE` again 0. BTW, there is nothing wrong with your code, it works fine for me